# extract pine script function data

Tags: function, variables, global

sample code please to extract data frm functions in a library?
thanks

using trading view zigzag library I need to extract data from it's functions

httpswww.tradingview.comscriptbzirugxc-zigzag

Answer (score 0):

export type Pivot
line  ln
label lb
bool  isHigh
float vol
Point start
Point end

var stend = Pivot.new()
plot(stend.vol)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).